# cloning a project without .sln from GitHub into visual studio 2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio, github

I am trying to clone a project without .sln from GitHub into visual studio 2015 using the instructions from Microsoft [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/clone?view=azdevops&tabs=visual-studio).

The project I am trying to clone from [GitHub](https://github.com/sineco/MyoDataCapture)

Can someone point out to me how to work with the project?

Comment: It looks like all the code for `myo.framework` is pre-compiled. You cannot simply reuse this on Windows without significant reverse-engineering work.

Answer (score 0):

This project has not been written with portability in mind. You must define a build system and toolchain in order to use it outside of XCode.

There's no easy path. Fortunatly, this is not a big project. I'd suggest to port it with CMake.

Comment: Forget about it. The myo.framework dependency has no source attached and it depends on the MacOS libSystem.so.